# Understanding fly.io Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building:

Tags: python, django, deployment

Hello everyone I am working in Django and I am trying to use fly.io. My specific question is why am I getting this error.

Error: failed to fetch an image or build form source: error building: executor failed running [b/bin/sh -c set -ex && pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt &&.

what did I try and what was I expecting?

answer: these are the commands I ran. is there a flaw in them?
Is there another series of commands that I can use to deploy on fly.io?

```
python -m pip install gunicorn==20.1.0 
I was instructed to create a requirements.txt python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt 

Than change allowed_hosts = [*] 

than I created a docker ignore file 
.venv/
*.sqlite3
.git 

git status
git add -A
git commit -m "new updates for deployment" 
git push -u origin main 
(.venv) $ fly launch
Creating app in ~/desktop/code/pages
Scanning source code
Detected a Django app
? Choose an app name (leave blank to generate one): dfb-ch3-pages
automatically selected personal organization: Will Vincent
? Choose a region for deployment: Boston, Massachusetts (US) (bos)
App will use 'bos' region as primary
Created app dfb-ch3-pages in organization 'personal'
Admin URL: https://fly.io/apps/dfb-ch3-pages
Hostname: dfb-ch3-pages.fly.dev
? Overwrite "/Users/wsv/Desktop/dfb_42/ch3-pages/.dockerignore"? No
Set secrets on dfb-ch3-pages: SECRET_KEY
? Would you like to set up a Postgresql database now? No
? Would you like to set up an Upstash Redis database now? No
Wrote config file fly.toml
Your app is ready! Deploy with `flyctl deploy`

(.venv) $ flyctl deploy


1 desired, 1 placed, 1 healthy, 0 unhealthy [health checks: 1 total, 1 passing]
--> v0 deployed successfully
(.venv) fly open 

What else have I tried?

I have tried looking at stack overflow articles. 
I have asking on discord for answers.
I have checked the documentation. 
I have tried asking on the fly.io forums. 

my files

requirements.txt

altgraph @ file:///System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
asgiref==3.7.2
black==23.7.0
click==8.1.5
Django==4.2.3
future @ file:///System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
gunicorn==20.1.0
macholib @ file:///System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/macholib-1.15.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
packaging==23.1
pathspec==0.11.1
platformdirs==3.8.1
six @ file:///System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sqlparse==0.4.4
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.7.1


# fly.toml app configuration file generated for dfb-ch3-pages-strikeouts27 on 2023-07-18T23:17:30-05:00
#
# See https://fly.io/docs/reference/configuration/ for information about how to use this file.
#

app = "dfb-ch3-pages-strikeouts27"
primary_region = "dfw"
console_command = "/code/manage.py shell"

[env]
  PORT = "8000"

[http_service]
  internal_port = 8000
  force_https = true
  auto_stop_machines = true
  auto_start_machines = true
  min_machines_running = 0
  processes = ["app"]

[[statics]]
  guest_path = "/code/static"
  url_prefix = "/static/"


Dockerfile

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11-slim-buster

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/
COPY . /code

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "2", "django_project.wsgi"]
```

github
https://github.com/strikeouts27/django_for_beginners

Comment: What's the full error, stack trace and all?

Comment: my question on fly.io  forum with more details

https://community.fly.io/t/trying-to-deploy-my-project-and-got-the-error-on-requirements-txt/14210/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my future reference all of these system/ pathways are useless. its better to place it in versions and have pypi install it.

the question I know have is how do I determine what to put for ==? Someone was able to figure that out. how do I figure out the values for these? Is there a default requirements file? or version commands?

```
altgraph==0.17.2
asgiref==3.7.2
black==23.7.0
click==8.1.5
Django==4.2.3
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
macholib==1.15.2
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
packaging==23.1
pathspec==0.11.1
platformdirs==3.8.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.7.1
```